# Pyplot : imshow 3D array with a slider

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 3d array

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

A = np.random.rand(10,5,5)
```

and I would like to to visualize each 5x5 image in `A`

```
for Ai in A:
    plt.imshow(Ai)
    plt.show()
```

Except that rather than having 5 figures like in the example above, I would like to have a slider to switch between indexes for the first coordinate of `A`.

For the moment, I have tried the following :

```
idx0 = 3
l = plt.imshow(A[idx0])

axidx = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
slidx = Slider(axidx, 'index', 0, 9, valinit=idx0, valfmt='%d')

def update(val):
    idx = slidx.val
    l.set_data(A[idx])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
slidx.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

But when I use the slider, the image in the plot doesn't change, and I get the message

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

How can I get my slider to work with my 3d array ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, the problem wasn't with the Slider at all, I just needed to convert the value returned by the slider into an `int`.

Replacing with

```
l.set_data(A[int(idx)])
```

does the trick